# What is the logarithmic color scales?(not logarithmic axes)

Tags: plotting, color, plot-themes

I have some density plots and an "advise". What does it mean?
" I also strongly recommend switching the color scales in this figure from linear to log, to make it even easier to see the region of instability."
What is the Log color scale?
How can I do this?
Note that, I think this is different with a density plot with logarithmic scales iv axis. 
 Tnx.

Comment: @corey979: No it is not my question!

Comment: Due to the lack of a concrete example, I can  only suggest that you use the `ColorFunction` option to change the scaling. E.g., you can use `ColorFunction -> ColorData["DarkRainbow"]@*Log10`, where `ColorData["DarkRainbow"]` stands for just any color function.

Comment: @corey979: I used this. The bar legend is disappeared! and all the figure goes gray :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dp1 = DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, 10, 100}, {y, 10, 100}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> 250 ] ;
```

In `DensityPlot[f, ...]` the argument of `func` in `ColorFunction  > func`  is the `f`. So using the option `ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, "Log"}` makes the coloring logarithmic.

```
dp2 = DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, 10, 100}, {y, 10, 100}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, "Log"}, ImageSize -> 250] ;
```

Alternatively, you can use scaled `ColorFunction` together with the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` to get the same result.

```
dp3 = DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, 10, 100}, {y, 10, 100}, 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"Rainbow", {Log@200, Log@20000}}][
       Log@#] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> 250];

 Row[{dp1, dp2, dp3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Does it related to the colors only? Or effects on the axis scales too? In fact, I have some negative values of the function in the density plot. Is it possible to have a logarithmic scaling yet?!

Comment: @PerfectFluid, it does not affect the axes scales. Color function argument is  the scaled value of the function `f` in the first argument of `DensityPlot`; so using `Log` scaling on the `f` values only changes the values supplied to `ColorFunction`. With negative and zero values you can't use log scaling (i think those values will be cropped.) Based on the graphs in your other question, I think the referee's suggestion doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Dear @kglr, I just installed a higher version of Mma, and `scaling functions` is active now. However, some parts of the density plot are white! I have tested the points of this region and did not equal to zero. What is the reason of this white area?!

Comment: @perfectfluid: be sure that you enable PlotRange->Full, if not mathematica cuts out  parts of your result that it deems too large or too small to fit on the plot.